# SearchKit: How can I do math on currencies?

Tags: searchkit, smarty, currency

I'm trying to replicate a (buggy) report in Extended Reports, basically:

| Campaign | Goal | Amount Raised | Amount Left |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Capital Campaign | $10,000 | $8,000 | $2,000 |
| Another Campaign | $15,000 | $6,000 | $9,000 |

The equivalent SQL would be:

```
SELECT campaign.title as "Campaign", campaign.goal_revenue AS "Goal", SUM(contrib.total_amount) AS "Amount Raised", goal_revenue - SUM(contrib.total_amount) as "Amount Left"
FROM civicrm_campaign campaign
JOIN civicrm_contribution contrib ON campaign.id = contrib.campaign_id
GROUP BY campaign.id;
```

However, there seems to be no way to do this.  SQL transformations won't work because I can't subtract the aggregated Amount Raised from Goal (or do arithmetic transforms on aggregated fields).  But Smarty treats the values as strings, with no way to convert to numbers (using `intval` filter or casting to `(int)`) both generate errors.

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to use Smarty to rewrite a random field to be the "Amount Left", but it's not pretty:

```
{capture name=goal assign=goal}[goal_revenue]{/capture}
{capture name=goal2 assign=goal}{$goal|replace:"$":""|replace:",":""}{/capture}
{capture name=raised assign=raised}[SUM_Campaign_Contribution_campaign_id_01_total_amount]{/capture}
{capture name=raised2 assign=raised}{$raised|replace:"$":""|replace:",":""}{/capture}
{capture name=remaining assign=remaining}{math equation="x - y" x=$goal y=$raised}{/capture}
{$remaining|crmMoney}
```

It seems like it would be easier if any of the following were true:

- A "raw" Smarty filter were available to pass my currency as a number.
- It's possible to use Smarty filters directly on SK tokens.
- It's possible to use arithmetic SQL transformations with aggregated values.
- A field transformation "Raw" existed to disable formatting.

Comment: I've tried to make raw values happen but haven't got it past review. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/26742